# Same start and end date in DateRangePicker using plotly dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I have used daterangepicker in my application.

There is a situation where is need to select start_date and end_date as same dates, so that I can view sales details on that particular day.

By default dateRangePicker makes me to select at least two days(ie 20/04/2020 - 21/04/2020) but I would like it to be (20/04/2020 - 20/04/2020) .

Id there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your DatePickerRange definition, pass `minimum_nights=0` , and then you should be able to select same dates.

```
dcc.DatePickerRange(
                   id='dates',
                   display_format="DD-MM-YY",
                   start_date = date.today(),
                   end_date = date.today(),
                   minimum_nights=0
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it must be done programatically. It depends on your specific implementation but you can create a callback to update the date picker range end_date when start_date is updated:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id="date-range-picker")
    ])

@app.callback(Output("date-range-picker", "end_date"),
              [Input("date-range-picker", "start_date")])
def update_start_date(start_date):
    return start_date

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Or you could simply set both via another callback say when a report button was clicked